# Receiving and responding to Twilio SMS using parse cloud module

Tags: parse-platform, twilio

I have a cloud code function that I use to send a text message to a number that is determined in my app (iOS).

The message sends fine, but I want the person who receives the message to be able to respond so that the original sender sees their response. I'm having trouble finding a way to do this using the Parse twilio module.

Here is what my cloud code function looks like right now:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendText", function(request, response) {
  // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
  twilio.sendSms({
    From: "+15555555555",
    To: request.params.number,
    Body: request.params.message
  }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
    error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
  });
});
```

Is it possible to just call this function again from its callback with the new recipient's number (the number of the original sender)?

Comment: From what I understand you want your users to be able to SMS themselves, why not use the built-in message composer and let them send/receive/PAY ?

Comment: You could still pre-fill everything and it would require only one clic from them. Though the twilio would require zero, but is more expensive.
Also, sometimes notifications are enough.

Comment: @Zil notifications aren't enough for some critical info I need to make sure users get. I decided to not use message composer because I thought it was important to hide as much personal info as possible (phone number) due to the nature of my app. But I will probably resort to that if I can't figure something else out or twilio becomes too expensive

Comment: Sending critical information coudl be done using simple webservice calls or parse objects, and they're pretty much free. Notifications (though unreliable) would help you notify your users that they indeed receive/sent data, and either way you can always fetch it when the app starts and if there was an object to fetch, show some indicator that there is new data.
That way, your users always get the data, are notified most of the time (really close to "all" the time), but you don't have to pay for text messages.

Comment: Also, text messages are incredibly intrusive, your app might even be rejected for that. I don't know what it does or how often you do it, but sending an SMS to a user for something else than a forgotten password or a pin code when you signup already feels like a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310514/allow-ios-app-users-to-place-calls-and-texts-to-each-other-through-twilio-number) question/answer I posted with a similar issue.

I use Twilio to anonymize calling and texting between users of my app. There's more info in my app about how I do this, but let me know if you have some questions.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from looking at this and (what I presume) was your github account.

Comment: Glad it could help. I'm sure it can be improved upon, but, hey, it works in my app ;)  And I'm not sure it was my Github... I only have a couple old VR projects on my public repos, my Parse/Twilio stuff should all be in private repos... I'ma go check and make sure I'm not leaking private keys hahaha

Comment: I just found some code snippets very similar to what you posted here. It could have been someone who saw your question when working on something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It seems you're trying to create what we call the masked phone numbers feature. This is a feature in which two users communicate through a central Twilio number and never find out each others' details. There is a [tutorial on how to accomplish this with both calls and SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails) however it is in Ruby on Rails. I recommend you take a read through as it gives you a good idea of how you'll need to implement this.

Then, if you have any more Parse/Node.js related questions on how to work on it, please drop me a line at philnash@twilio.com.

Comment: Didn't know there was such a thing, a twilio evangelist ! ^^

Comment: There's more than just me too. We're a friendly group though, so come and say hi!

Comment: Thanks. this was very insightful. I was hoping it would be achievable without having to buy lots of numbers, but it doesn't seem possible as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know who sent the message you need the recipient to be able to get the sender's number, so he can call the function again himself.

There are many ways to do that, your idea seems alright, you could add the sender's phone number as a parameter in the cloud function, and use it in the call back when you use sendSMS a second time.

Here is one way to do it :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendText", function(request, response) {
  // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
  twilio.sendSms({
    From: "+15555555555",
    To: request.params.recipientnumber,   //Notice I changed the paramter name here
    Body: request.params.recipientmessage //Notice I changed the paramter name here
  }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) { 

      twilio.sendSms({
    From: "+15555555555",
    To: request.params.sendernumber,      //Notice I changed the paramter name here
    Body: request.params.sendermessage    //Notice I changed the paramter name here
  }, {
    success: function(httpResponse) { 

      response.success("SMS sent!"); 
   },
    error: function(httpResponse) { 
       response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); 
   }
  });
   },
    error: function(httpResponse) { 
       response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); 
   }
  });
});
```

If the first call succeeds, make another one, if that one succeeds, return success. If either fail, return failure and never start another call.

But make sure you understand this, this will pretty much send both sms at the same time, most of the time. Your sender won't get the feeling that it was a response (or it was a fast one !).

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve, that's why I posted some comments to suggest something else, but I still wanted to answer here about your exact question.

Comment: This is basically what I had in mind, but I wasn't sure if it would work. I may test it and go from there. 

And to answer your question about what I'm trying to achieve, imagine an app like airb&b or uber where it's critical that the users can communicate reliably as a "deadline" approaches. I do send push notifications, but for the most important notifications, I think I also need a text message, and I would like users to be able to respond directly to my twilio number so that the original sender sees their response (in a text message)